# Prove that there are positive real solutions to $x+y=xyz \land xy=x+z \land y+z=yz$

Tags: real-numbers

For $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$, how can I prove that there are solutions to this set of equations,

$$x+y=xyz \land xy=x+z \land y+z=yz$$
in a legitimate way, not by feeding it to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2By%3Dxyz%2C+xy+%3D+x%2Bz%2C+y%2Bz%3Dyz)?

I have found out that

$x = \frac{y}{yz-1} = \frac{z}{y-1}$

$y = \frac{x}{xz-1} = \frac{x+z}{x} = \frac{z}{z-1}$

$z = \frac{x+y}{xy} = xy-x = \frac{y}{y-1}$

but I am not sure how to progress from there.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions can be parametrized by
$$
x=y - 2, \quad z=y^2 - 3y + 2,
$$
where $y$ has to satisfy the equation
$$
y^3 - 4y^2 + 4y - 2=0.
$$
Every cubic polynomial has a real root, and this one has a positive one satisfying $y>2$. So we are done, since $x,z>0$ for any $y>2$.

Comment: it's not a typo, it is probably not supposed to be an integer solution so it's not that easy

Comment: OK, then my solution is correct.

Comment: I am still worried that this solution doesn't really eliminate the need for a calculator. I don't think the author of the exercise meant to use the brutal cubic formula which I would probably need here, but thanks regardless.

Comment: You don't have to use the "brutal" cubic formula. You can do this much easier to see that the real root is positive.

Comment: positive - sure, but I still have to work with $x=y-2$ for example, where $y > 0$ isn't enough to tell whether x is positive or not. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You only need that $y>2$, right? And this is clear by an easy estimate, without a brutal formula. I have edited this.